# Most Efficient Way of Updating One Table with Most Recent Record from another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a simple update statement that takes data from one table and inserts into another.  The problem is that the table where the data resides may have one or more records so I want to use the most recent record that contains data.

Here is my code and mind you this code works just fine initially.  My worry though is if I have a situation where there are multiple records,  I want to update the most recent record's data.  The table with the data does have a DateTimeEntered field to utilize:

```
Update C
Set C.CaseNumber = L.Docket_NO
From dbo.Cases as C
Inner Join dbo.messages as L
on L.AccountID = C.AccountID
where (L.Docket_NO <> '' and L.Docket_NO != C.CaseNumber)
or (L.Docket_NO <> '' and C.CaseNumber is Null)
```

So If I try the CTE method I would do something like this:

```
With CTE_Messages as (Select AccountID, DOCKET_NO, DateTimeEntered from dbo.messages where DateTimeEntered = (Select MAX(DateTimeEntered) from dbo.messages))

Update C
Set C.CaseNumber = L.Docket_NO
From dbo.Cases as C
Inner Join CTE_Messages as L
on L.AccountID = C.AccountID
where (L.Docket_NO <> '' and L.Docket_NO != C.CaseNumber)
or (L.Docket_NO <> '' and C.CaseNumber is Null)
```

Do I need to insert the where and/or clause into the CTE as well to get the pertinent data?  Am I thinking too hard on this where the CTE isn't needed and I just need to put a subquery on the Set and Find the Max datetimeentered there?

I am really just looking for the most efficient way of accomplishing this.  Can anyone help this SQL neophyte?  Any insight would be most appreciated.

Edit:  Thank you for the answers.  But here is my main problem.

I originally used something like this:

```
  Update C
  Set C.CaseNumber = L.Docket_NO
  From dbo.CourtCases as C
  Inner Join dbo.messages as L
   on L.AccountID = C.AccountID
  where (L.Docket_NO <> '' and L.Docket_NO != C.CaseNumber)
  or (L.Docket_NO <> '' and C.CaseNumber is Null)
```

This simple update statement worked until I realized that I don't know what record SQL is pulling from dbo.messages to update CourtCases.CaseNumber.  Dbo.Messages is somewhat of a historical table and there could potentially be multiple records.  Some of these records will be different or old and they need to be updated.  I originally latched onto Datetimeentered from dbo.messages to give me the most recent item but the problem is that not every record in dbo.messages contains a Docket_NO to use.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you can add another where ('and' in this case) to choose the most recent record:

```
Update C
Set C.CaseNumber = L.Docket_NO
From dbo.Cases as C
Inner Join dbo.messages as L
on L.AccountID = C.AccountID
where (L.Docket_NO <> '' and L.Docket_NO != C.CaseNumber)
or (L.Docket_NO <> '' and C.CaseNumber is Null)
**and c.casenumber = (Select c.casenumber from cases where datetimeentered =
(select max(datetimeentered) from cases)**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_Number() to identify the most recent record on the fly. If you wanted to do this in reverse and only update the most recent `[dbo].[messages]` record with the `[dbo].[Cases]`'s `CaseNumber`, using similar logic you could update the CTE and it would update the most recent record within the CTE dataset. If you wanted to update the second most recent record you'd just update the 1 to a 2 in the Join logic...

```
With    CTE As
(
        Select  Row_Number() Over (Partition By AccountID Order By DateTimeEntered Desc) As recentID,
                AccountID,
                Docket_NO
        From    dbo.messages
        Where   Docket_NO <> ''
)
Update  C
Set     CaseNumber = L.Docket_NO
From    dbo.Cases as C
Inner   Join CTE as L
        On  L.AccountID = C.AccountID
        And L.recentID = 1
Where   L.Docket_NO != C.CaseNumber 
Or      C.CaseNumber Is Null
```